# Rails Unique Constraints Model + Database Level and Race Conditions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-migrations

I currently have the following migration for my UserGroups has_many :through association:

```
class CreateUserGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_groups do |t|
      t.integer :user_id, :null => false
      t.integer :group_id, :null => false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

With the following model and unique constraint:

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  validates_uniqueness_of :user, :scope => :group, :message => :not_unique
end
```

The uniqueness validation is working great, but what if competing threads in my application cause a race condition and it makes past the application-level check?  How can I write a migration to protect against a duplicate row in my join table for users and groups at the database level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an unique index

```
add_index :user_groups, [:user_id, :group_id], unique: true
```

Comment: that's it? Will this work bi-directionally, or if a group adds a user / user adds a group?

Comment: Yes, it's bi-directional.

Comment: The order doesn't matter for uniqueness, however the index is only used when querying if you're querying on the first column or both. That is will be used for `select * from user_groups where user_id = 1` but not for `select * from user_groups where group_id = 1`.

Comment: But note that this will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` exception if the unique constraint in the database is violated rather than simply failing validation in the usual way.

Comment: yes, I know that @muistooshort, thanks!  Lookup is done in both directions very frequently, so would I want to add another index? `add_index :user_groups, [:group_id, :user_id], unique: true`

Comment: Well, you don't need two unique indexes, so just add either `add_index :user_groups , [:group_id]` or `[:group_id, :user_id]`